# Deploying docker images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have a nodejs server app and a separate reacts client app.
I have created docker images for both and a docker compose at the top level to build and run both

I'm struggling to understand how I can deploy/host these somewhere?
Do I deploy both separate images to the docker register? Or is this a way of hosting this on it's own as an entire docker container?

Answer (score 1):

Docker Registry is storage for built images. Think it as location for compiled "binaries" if comparing regular software.

Regularly, you might have some kind of CI for your source code, and when you trigger it for example by committing into 'master' branch, new image is built on the CI. It can push it into registry for long term storing, or push it directly to your hosting server (or registry in your server).

You can configure your docker-compose to pull latest images from private registry, when you just rerun it in your server.
Basically, hosting happens when you just run `docker-compose up` in some server, if you have done required configurations. It really depends where you are going to host them.

Maybe helpful:

- https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/
- https://medium.com/@stoyanov.veseline/pushing-docker-images-to-a-private-registry-with-docker-compose-d2797097751

Answer (score 1):

If you've already built the docker images on local, you can use [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com) for hosting the docker images. If you're using Github Actions [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lavish10/5f870660fb6b4c4ba01bac1ee4a48003) script can be helpful.